# USB 3.0 docking station and dedicated graphic

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a [XMG C405 notebook](http://www.xmg.gg/c405/?LANG=UK), with integrated and dedicated graphic cards, and a [Dell D3100 docking station](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/4/SLN296254/en). The docking station is connected via USB 3.0.

Currently my notebook always runs all applications on the integrated card, cause this card is connected to the docking station. That causes games and Photoshop to have a very poor performance. Is it possible to tell the notebook to use the dedicated card instead of the integrated even though the docking station is connected via USB 3.0?

Comment: Typically, the GPU is chosen based on load and work type in dual-gpu situations. Have you updated the drivers for your GPUs to the latest available version?

Comment: Both are the latest versions. The Nvidia system control claims that no screen is connected via the Nvidia graphics. That is my problem

Comment: Why are you using the docking station? Can't you plug your laptop into a wall socket?

Comment: The docking station is nor for power, it is too extend the ports my laptop has.

Comment: Does this dock use the Display Link drivers?

Comment: @music2myear Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think I am: DisplayLink only connects to the Primary Video Controller. In your case, the onboard Intel graphics on your CPU.

If your BIOS allows for disabling the Intel graphics this may be a viable solution, though it will result in higher battery usage. However, when docked this isn't a problem.

I cannot find any recent documentation explicitly stating this.

However, there are [older forum post](https://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?s=0f562123ccd0d4d96bca3c0fc917152b&t=48&page=4)s that allude to this issue claiming it is intrinsic to the DisplayLink architecture, and more recent [official support documents](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/544297-is-my-windows-computer-compatible-with-displaylink) state that the primary video controller drivers must be fully up to date, and nothing it stated about secondary controllers.

While USB 3 has sufficient bandwidth to handle the necessary communication throughput to support the higher-powered secondary GPUs in many laptops, DisplayLink itself was designed as an office solution, not an engineering or gaming solution.

Once again, I may be proven wrong, but I have not yet found any documentation that would indicate that I am.

Comment: I checked and apparently I cannot disable the Intel card. I will just connect one of the screens via Hdmi then it works.